# With float right button page layout is broken

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

In my  jQuery v3.3.1 / Bootstrap v4.1.2 application I try to add button at right top of the page.
Please open http://demo2.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk/admin/clients
It is under credentials   admin@demo.com 111111

with code :

```
<section class="card-body content_block_admin_clients_wrapper ">

    <h1 class="card-title">Manage Clients</h1>


    <div class="row float-right mr-3">
        <button type="button" onclick="javascript:document.location='{{ url('/admin/clients/create') }}'" class="btn btn-primary ">
            <span class="btn-label"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-submit-button"></i></span>&nbsp;Add new client
        </button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </div>


    <div class="row ">
```

I have the button, but in this case all data table area is move from right .
It must not be so.

Without this button it looks like http://demo2.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk/admin/warehouses

How to fix it ?

**UPDATED # 1 :**
With proposed by Katy H. decision button is below of search input, but I need it between 
title and search input, something like that https://imgur.com/a/AbTrlQH
but  as new line and without gap at right of the right of he data grid.
Could you please to look at provided link one more time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Try moving the button inside your "search" row like this...

```
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 mb-3">
                <input class="form-control editable_field string_input " value="" id="filter_name" name="filter_name" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter search string">
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 mb-3 mt-1 pl-2">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Search" onclick="javascript:backendClient.runSearch(oTable); return false;" id="btn_run_search">
            </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 mb-3 mt-1 pl-2">
            <button type="button" onclick="javascript:document.location='http://demo2.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk/admin/clients/create'" class="btn btn-primary ">
                <span class="btn-label"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-submit-button"></i></span>&nbsp;Add new client
            </button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </div>

            <div class="table-responsive">
                <div id="get-client-dt-listing-table_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper no-footer"><div class="dataTables_length" id="get-client-dt-listing-table_length"><label>Show <select name="get-client-dt-listing-table_length" aria-controls="get-client-dt-listing-table" class=""><option value="25">25</option><option value="50">50</option><option value="100">100</option><option value="200">200</option><option value="-1">All</option></select> entries</label>. Shows 25 of 1093 clients</div><div id="get-client-dt-listing-table_filter" class="dataTables_filter" style="display: none;"><label>Search:<input type="search" class="" placeholder="" aria-controls="get-client-dt-listing-table"></label></div><div id="get-client-dt-listing-table_processing" class="dataTables_processing" style="display: none;">Loading clients...</div><table class="table table-bordered table-striped text-primary dataTable no-footer" id="get-client-dt-listing-table" role="grid" aria-describedby="get-client-dt-listing-table_info" style="width: 1439px;">
                    <thead>
                    <tr role="row"><th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="get-client-dt-listing-table" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Id: activate to sort column descending" style="width: 42px;">Id</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="get-client-dt-listing-table" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Full Name: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 173px;">Full Name</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="get-client-dt-listing-table" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Lead Type: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 141px;">Lead Type</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="get-client-dt-listing-table" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Customer Type: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 201px;">Customer Type</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="get-client-dt-listing-table" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Account Type: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 183px;">Account Type</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="get-client-dt-listing-table" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="PO box: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 142px;">PO box</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="get-client-dt-listing-table" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Office fax: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 173px;">Office fax</th><th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="" style="width: 22px;"></th><th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="" style="width: 20px;"></th></tr>
                    </thead>
                <tbody><tr role="row" class="odd"><td class="sorting_1">1</td><td>full_name # 1</td><td>type # 1</td><td>SS</td><td></td><td>po_box # 1</td><td>office_fax # 1</td><td><a href="/admin/clients/1/edit"><i class=" fa fa-edit"></i></a></td><td><a href="#" onclick="javascript:backendClient.deleteClient(1,'full_name # 1')"><i class="fa fa-remove a_link"></i></a></td></tr><tr role="row" class="even"><td class="sorting_1">2</td><td>full_name # 2</td><td>type # 2</td><td>SS</td><td></td><td>po_box # 2</td><td>office_fax # 2</td><td><a href="/admin/clients/2/edit"><i class=" fa fa-edit"></i></a></td><td><a href="#" onclick="javascript:backendClient.deleteClient(2,'full_name # 2')"><i class="fa fa-remove a_link"></i></a></td></tr><tr role="row" class="odd"><td class="sorting_1">3</td><td>full_name # 3</td><td>type # 3</td><td>SS</td><td></td><td>po_box # 3</td><td>office_fax # 3</td><td><a href="/admin/clients/3/edit"><i class=" fa fa-edit"></i></a></td><td><a href="#" onclick="javascript:backendClient.deleteClient(3,'full_name # 3')"><i class="fa fa-remove a_link"></i></a></td></tr><tr role="row" class="even"><td class="sorting_1">4</td><td>full_name # 4</td><td>type # 4</td><td>SS</td><td></td><td>po_box # 4</td><td>office_fax # 4</td><td><a href="/admin/clients/4/edit"><i class=" fa fa-edit"></i></a></td><td><a href="#" onclick="javascript:backendClient.deleteClient(4,'full_name # 4')"><i class="fa fa-remove a_link"></i></a></td></tr><tr role="row" class="odd"><td class="sorting_1">5</td><td>full_name # 5</td><td>type # 5</td><td>SS</td><td></td><td>po_box # 5</td><td>office_fax # 5</td><td><a href="/admin/clients/5/edit"><i class=" fa fa-edit"></i></a></td><td><a href="#" onclick="javascript:backendClient.deleteClient(5,'full_name # 5')"><i class="fa fa-remove a_link"></i></a></td></tr><tr role="row" class="even"><td class="sorting_1">6</td><td>full_name # 6</td><td>type # 6</td><td>SS</td><td></td><td>po_box # 6</td><td>office_fax # 6</td><td><a href="/admin/clients/6/edit"><i class=" fa fa-edit"></i></a></td><td><a href="#" onclick="javascript:backendClient.deleteClient(6,'full_name # 6')"><i class="fa fa-remove a_link"></i></a></td></tr><tr role="row" class="odd"><td class="sorting_1">7</td><td>full_name # 7</td><td>type # 7</td><td>SS</td><td></td><td>po_box # 7</td><td>office_fax # 7</td><td><a href="/admin/clients/7/edit"><i class=" fa fa-edit"></i></a></td><td><a href="#" onclick="javascript:backendClient.deleteClient(7,'full_name # 7')"><i class="fa fa-remove a_link"></i></a></td></tr><tr role="row" class="even"><td class="sorting_1">8</td><td>full_name # 8</td><td>type # 8</td><td>SS</td><td></td><td>po_box # 8</td><td>office_fax # 8</td><td><a href="/admin/clients/8/edit"><i class=" fa fa-edit"></i></a></td><td><a href="#" onclick="javascript:backendClient.deleteClient(8,'full_name # 8')"><i class="fa fa-remove a_link"></i></a></td></tr><tr role="row" class="odd"><td class="sorting_1">9</td><td>full_name # 9</td><td>type # 9</td><td>SS</td><td></td><td>po_box # 9</td><td>office_fax # 9</td><td><a href="/admin/clients/9/edit"><i class=" fa fa-edit"></i></a></td><td><a href="#" onclick="javascript:backendClient.deleteClient(9,'full_name # 9')"><i class="fa fa-remove a_link"></i></a></td></tr><tr role="row" class="even"><td class="sorting_1">10</td><td>full_name # 10</td><td>type # 10</td><td>SS</td><td></td><td>po_box # 10</td><td>office_fax # 10</td><td><a href="/admin/clients/10/edit"><i class=" fa fa-edit"></i></a></td><td><a href="#" onclick="javascript:backendClient.deleteClient(10,'full_name # 10')"><i class="fa fa-remove a_link"></i></a></td></tr><tr role="row" class="odd"><td class="sorting_1">11</td><td>full_name # 11</td><td>type # 11</td><td>SS</td><td></td><td>po_box # 11</td><td>office_fax # 11</td><td><a href="/admin/clients/11/edit"><i class=" fa fa-edit"></i></a></td><td><a href="#" onclick="javascript:backendClient.deleteClient(11,'full_name # 11')"><i class="fa fa-remove a_link"></i></a></td></tr><tr role="row" class="even"><td class="sorting_1">12</td><td>full_name # 12</td><td>type # 12</td><td>SS</td><td></td><td>po_box # 12</td><td>office_fax # 12</td><td><a href="/admin/clients/12/edit"><i class=" fa fa-edit"></i></a></td><td><a href="#" onclick="javascript:backendClient.deleteClient(12,'full_name # 12')"><i class="fa fa-remove a_link"></i></a></td></tr><tr role="row" class="odd"><td class="sorting_1">13</td><td>full_name # 13</td><td>type # 13</td><td>SS</td><td></td><td>po_box # 13</td><td>office_fax # 13</td><td><a href="/admin/clients/13/edit"><i class=" fa fa-edit"></i></a></td><td><a href="#" onclick="javascript:backendClient.deleteClient(13,'full_name # 13')"><i class="fa fa-remove a_link"></i></a></td></tr><tr role="row" class="even"><td class="sorting_1">14</td><td>full_name # 14</td><td>type # 14</td><td>SS</td><td></td><td>po_box # 14</td><td>office_fax # 14</td><td><a href="/admin/clients/14/edit"><i class=" fa fa-edit"></i></a></td><td><a href="#" onclick="javascript:backendClient.deleteClient(14,'full_name # 14')"><i class="fa fa-remove a_link"></i></a></td></tr><tr role="row" class="odd"><td class="sorting_1">15</td><td>full_name # 15</td><td>type # 15</td><td>SS</td><td></td><td>po_box # 15</td><td>office_fax # 15</td><td><a href="/admin/clients/15/edit"><i class=" fa fa-edit"></i></a></td><td><a href="#" onclick="javascript:backendClient.deleteClient(15,'full_name # 15')"><i class="fa fa-remove a_link"></i></a></td></tr><tr role="row" class="even"><td class="sorting_1">16</td><td>full_name # 16</td><td>type # 16</td><td>SS</td><td></td><td>po_box # 16</td><td>office_fax # 16</td><td><a href="/admin/clients/16/edit"><i class=" fa fa-edit"></i></a></td><td><a href="#" onclick="javascript:backendClient.deleteClient(16,'full_name # 16')"><i class="fa fa-remove a_link"></i></a></td></tr><tr role="row" class="odd"><td class="sorting_1">17</td><td>full_name # 17</td><td>type # 17</td><td>SS</td><td></td><td>po_box # 17</td><td>office_fax # 17</td><td><a href="/admin/clients/17/edit"><i class=" fa fa-edit"></i></a></td><td><a href="#" onclick="javascript:backendClient.deleteClient(17,'full_name # 17')"><i class="fa fa-remove a_link"></i></a></td></tr><tr role="row" class="even"><td class="sorting_1">18</td><td>full_name # 18</td><td>type # 18</td><td>SS</td><td></td><td>po_box # 18</td><td>office_fax # 18</td><td><a href="/admin/clients/18/edit"><i class=" fa fa-edit"></i></a></td><td><a href="#" onclick="javascript:backendClient.deleteClient(18,'full_name # 18')"><i class="fa fa-remove a_link"></i></a></td></tr><tr role="row" class="odd"><td class="sorting_1">19</td><td>full_name # 19</td><td>type # 19</td><td>SS</td><td></td><td>po_box # 19</td><td>office_fax # 19</td><td><a href="/admin/clients/19/edit"><i class=" fa fa-edit"></i></a></td><td><a href="#" onclick="javascript:backendClient.deleteClient(19,'full_name # 19')"><i class="fa fa-remove a_link"></i></a></td></tr><tr role="row" class="even"><td class="sorting_1">20</td><td>full_name # 20</td><td>type # 20</td><td>SS</td><td></td><td>po_box # 20</td><td>office_fax # 20</td><td><a href="/admin/clients/20/edit"><i class=" fa fa-edit"></i></a></td><td><a href="#" onclick="javascript:backendClient.deleteClient(20,'full_name # 20')"><i class="fa fa-remove a_link"></i></a></td></tr><tr role="row" class="odd"><td class="sorting_1">21</td><td>full_name # 21</td><td>type # 21</td><td>SS</td><td></td><td>po_box # 21</td><td>office_fax # 21</td><td><a href="/admin/clients/21/edit"><i class=" fa fa-edit"></i></a></td><td><a href="#" onclick="javascript:backendClient.deleteClient(21,'full_name # 21')"><i class="fa fa-remove a_link"></i></a></td></tr><tr role="row" class="even"><td class="sorting_1">22</td><td>full_name # 22</td><td>type # 22</td><td>SS</td><td></td><td>po_box # 22</td><td>office_fax # 22</td><td><a href="/admin/clients/22/edit"><i class=" fa fa-edit"></i></a></td><td><a href="#" onclick="javascript:backendClient.deleteClient(22,'full_name # 22')"><i class="fa fa-remove a_link"></i></a></td></tr><tr role="row" class="odd"><td class="sorting_1">23</td><td>full_name # 23</td><td>type # 23</td><td>SS</td><td></td><td>po_box # 23</td><td>office_fax # 23</td><td><a href="/admin/clients/23/edit"><i class=" fa fa-edit"></i></a></td><td><a href="#" onclick="javascript:backendClient.deleteClient(23,'full_name # 23')"><i class="fa fa-remove a_link"></i></a></td></tr><tr role="row" class="even"><td class="sorting_1">24</td><td>full_name # 24</td><td>type # 24</td><td>SS</td><td></td><td>po_box # 24</td><td>office_fax # 24</td><td><a href="/admin/clients/24/edit"><i class=" fa fa-edit"></i></a></td><td><a href="#" onclick="javascript:backendClient.deleteClient(24,'full_name # 24')"><i class="fa fa-remove a_link"></i></a></td></tr><tr role="row" class="odd"><td class="sorting_1">25</td><td>full_name # 25</td><td>type # 25</td><td>SS</td><td></td><td>po_box # 25</td><td>office_fax # 25</td><td><a href="/admin/clients/25/edit"><i class=" fa fa-edit"></i></a></td><td><a href="#" onclick="javascript:backendClient.deleteClient(25,'full_name # 25')"><i class="fa fa-remove a_link"></i></a></td></tr></tbody></table><div class="dataTables_info" id="get-client-dt-listing-table_info" role="status" aria-live="polite" style="display: none;">Showing 1 to 25 of 1,093 entries</div><div class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers" id="get-client-dt-listing-table_paginate" style="display: block;"><a class="paginate_button previous disabled" aria-controls="get-client-dt-listing-table" data-dt-idx="0" tabindex="0" id="get-client-dt-listing-table_previous">Previous</a><span><a class="paginate_button current" aria-controls="get-client-dt-listing-table" data-dt-idx="1" tabindex="0">1</a><a class="paginate_button " aria-controls="get-client-dt-listing-table" data-dt-idx="2" tabindex="0">2</a><a class="paginate_button " aria-controls="get-client-dt-listing-table" data-dt-idx="3" tabindex="0">3</a><a class="paginate_button " aria-controls="get-client-dt-listing-table" data-dt-idx="4" tabindex="0">4</a><a class="paginate_button " aria-controls="get-client-dt-listing-table" data-dt-idx="5" tabindex="0">5</a><span class="ellipsis">…</span><a class="paginate_button " aria-controls="get-client-dt-listing-table" data-dt-idx="6" tabindex="0">44</a></span><a class="paginate_button next" aria-controls="get-client-dt-listing-table" data-dt-idx="7" tabindex="0" id="get-client-dt-listing-table_next">Next</a></div></div>

            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!
Could you please to look at UPDATED # 1 ?

Comment: Did you see that the class changed for your submit? from col-sm-6 to col-sm-3. This allows the div to fit nicely on the same line.